# Yii uploading file fails

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, yii

I am uploading a file using a `fileField` form `CActiveForm` and it works for 'small' files, but when I upload a larger file, the page just reloads with a blank form and nothing in either the `$_POST` or `$_FILES` variable.

My form has '`htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'` and the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are both set to 100M in `php.ini`

I'm using **Yii 1.1.14** and **PHP 5.5.12**.

The file model, nothing special

```
class DocumentUploadModel extends CFormModel {
    public $thefile;

    public function rules () {
        return array (
            array ('thefile', 'file', 'types' => 'pdf'),
        );
    }
}
```

The `filefield`, also nothing special

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($documentFile,'thefile'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($documentFile,'thefile'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($documentFile,'thefile'); ?>
</div>
```

Var dumps from small file, 344KB  (top = $_POST, bottom is $_FILES

[image: Var dumps from small file, 344KB (top = $_POST, bottom is $_FILES]

And the same for a larger file, 22.405K

[image: And the same for a larger file, 22.405KB]

I hope somebody can help me!

Comment: What your `saveAs()` returns? If it's false you can get error with `getError()` for your CUploadedFile.

Comment: It doesn't even get there, when I check if $_POST['Documents'] or $_FILES['DocumentUploadModel'] is set it fails. As seen in the second image, both $_POST and $_FILES are empty when I attempt to upload the larger file.

Comment: What is your memory limit? try `ini_set( 'memory_limit', '200M' );`

Comment: It was 128M (default), I tried to set it to 200 as you suggested and it showed this error on top now:
Warning: POST Content-Length of 22942745 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Since I tried to raise memory_limit, post_max_size and uploas_max_filesize to 1000M in php.ini and restarted services but the error remains the same.

Comment: It says your `post_max_size` is 3mb. You can watch it via `echo ini_get("post_max_size");` mm, maybe wrong config)

Comment: Hmm, thats indeed logging 3M :l I'll try setting the variables in my code instead of php.ini. Strange that it doesn't take the values i entered in php.ini

Comment: Found it, it was taking the php.ini from the apache folder instead of the php folder :l Thanks inseersa!

Answer (score 0):

edit the validation rule to:

`array ('thefile', 'file', 'types' => 'pdf', 'allowEmpty'=>false),`

Change the file upload size limit as per your requirement in php.ini and apache config.